# Jquery UI Dialog multiple dialog creation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have searched almost every single thing here and over the internet but i can't get this code to work. I am trying to get dialog box open when user click on php generated link which loads another page and it has a form etc.
click on some link, it'll generate a popup, close it and then click some other or the same link, it won't open the popup.

This is how my html is being generated

```
echo '<div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number='.$order_numbers.'&product_id='.$row['id'].'&quantity='.$row['quantity'].'&sale_price='.$row['sale_price'].'&id='.$row['order_product_id'].'" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>'.$row['productname'].'</h3></div>
    <div class=quantity><h3>'.$row['quantity'].'</h3></div>
    <div class=sale_price><h3>'.$row['sale_price'].'</h3></div></a>';
```

Jquery Code on Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $('.dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        hide: "slide",
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var url = $('.header a').attr('href');
            alert(url);
            $(".dialog").load(url); //use the previously saved id
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            alert("ali");
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });

    $('.header a').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.dialog').dialog('open');
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Actual HTML from Firefox Ctrl + u:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ko.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
//custom binding to initialize a jQuery UI button
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

        //handle disposal
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).button("destroy");
        }); 

        $(element).button(options);  
    }    
};

ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).dialog({
            close: function() {
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
                   value(null);   
                }
            }
        }); 

        //handle disposal
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
        }); 
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).dialog(value ? "open" : "close");   
    }
};

//wrapper to an observable that requires accept/cancel
ko.protectedObservable = function(initialValue) {
    //private variables
    var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue);
    var _tempValue = initialValue;

    //dependentObservable that we will return
    var result = ko.dependentObservable({
        //always return the actual value
        read: function() {
           return _actualValue(); 
        },
        //stored in a temporary spot until commit
        write: function(newValue) {
             _tempValue = newValue; 
        }
    }); 

    //if different, commit temp value
    result.commit = function() {
        if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
             _actualValue(_tempValue); 
        }  
    };

    //force subscribers to take original
    result.reset = function() {
        _actualValue.valueHasMutated();
        _tempValue = _actualValue();   //reset temp value 
    };

    return result;
};

function Item(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = ko.protectedObservable(name);  
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item(1, "one"),
        new Item(2, "two"),
        new Item(3, "three")
    ]);

    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.accept = function() {
       self.selectedItem().name.commit();
       self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.cancel = function() {
       self.selectedItem().name.reset();
       self.selectedItem(null);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

$("#items").delegate(".item", "click", function() {
    var context = ko.contextFor(this);
    context.$root.selectedItem(context.$data);
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        hide: "slide",
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var url = $('.header a').attr('href');
            alert(url);
            $(".dialog").load(url); //use the previously saved id
        }
    });


    //alert('');
    $('.header a').bind("click", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('.dialog').dialog('open');
        //$('#dialog').load(url);
    });
});    
â€‹</script>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="style">
    <div class="dialog"></div>
<div id=header1><div class=header><div class=order_number><h1>Order Number:</h1><h3>1000</h3></div><div class=h2><h2>Products</h2></div><br />
                     <div class=container><div class=product_name><h3>Products</h3></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>Quantity</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>Sale Price</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=1000&product_id=14&quantity=8619&sale_price=98769&id=66" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Valium Diazepam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>8619</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>98769</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=1000&product_id=41&quantity=1264&sale_price=193248&id=77" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>hhhha</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>1264</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>193248</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=1000&product_id=37&quantity=-1435&sale_price=1302&id=78" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Tamezepaam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>-1435</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>1302</h3></div></div></div><div class=header><div class=order_number><h1>Order Number:</h1><h3>128</h3></div><div class=h2><h2>Products</h2></div><br />
                     <div class=container><div class=product_name><h3>Products</h3></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>Quantity</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>Sale Price</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=128&product_id=37&quantity=-1435&sale_price=1568&id=81" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Tamezepaam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>-1435</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>1568</h3></div></div></div><div class=header><div class=order_number><h1>Order Number:</h1><h3>200</h3></div><div class=h2><h2>Products</h2></div><br />
                     <div class=container><div class=product_name><h3>Products</h3></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>Quantity</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>Sale Price</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=200&product_id=37&quantity=-1435&sale_price=14400&id=70" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Tamezepaam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>-1435</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>14400</h3></div></div></div><div class=header><div class=order_number><h1>Order Number:</h1><h3>300</h3></div><div class=h2><h2>Products</h2></div><br />
                     <div class=container><div class=product_name><h3>Products</h3></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>Quantity</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>Sale Price</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=300&product_id=37&quantity=-1435&sale_price=1344&id=73" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Tamezepaam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>-1435</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>1344</h3></div><div class=product_name><a href="edit_order.php?order_number=300&product_id=14&quantity=8619&sale_price=1344&id=80" style="text-decoration: none" title="View Details"><h3>Valium Diazepam</h3></a></div>
             <div class=quantity><h3>8619</h3></div>
             <div class=sale_price><h3>1344</h3></div></div></div></div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: So what's happening? Is the dialog not opening? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: I have a plugin that simplifies multiple dialog creation with jQuery: https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/dialogwrapper/wiki/Home. Maybe it can help

Comment: yes the dialog doesnot open at all. It appears like something is dead and sometimes it moves to the edit_order.php?rest-of-the-link

Comment: I see your plugin but can it load other page too ?

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar is your link formed as a valid html? It appears to me as a mess of tags. (in your first example)

Comment: @caligula It comes like this in the alert box, i am not a very good jquery programmer just like a beginner edit_order.php?order_number=1000&product_id=14&quantity=8619&sale_price=98769&id=66

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar can you post actual html as browser gets it. From `Ctrl` + `u` in Firefox

Comment: @caligula i have added the complete html code from firefox in my question

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar first of all make a valid html. You have unclosed `<a>` tag in your first example where `<a href="edit_order.php?`

Comment: @caligula It is closing down here
`<div class=sale_price><h3>'.$row['sale_price'].'</h3></div></a>';`

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar no man. It is not closed, cause before closing `</a>` you have a closing `</div>` for `<div class=product_name>`. Make a valid html, without that there is nothing to do further

Comment: @caligula just updated the html and now it is closing on product name but still stuck on same page on 2nd click issue.

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar what `</table>` closing tag is doing on your example? Without normal html there is no sense to watch js-dom errors, cause actual dom model 100% malformed

Comment: @caligula the table structure was actually commented and 1 tag was left open, fixed this too and still same issue.

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar where is `.dialog` element?

Comment: @caligula `<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="style">
    <div class="dialog"></div>` 
Here Sir

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar now please clarify your problem. What is wrong. My local example of yours seems to work well. It does not open more than once, that is your issue?

Comment: Sir click on some link, it'll generate a popup, close it and then click some link, it won't open the popup :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the call of the `dialog` method in the close callback with the `destroy` argument. You have:

```
close: function(event, ui) {
    alert("ali");
    $(this).dialog('destroy');
}
```

inside you call `$(this).dialog('destroy');` that is why it does work only once.

that is the code that works for me, try substitute it for your one:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        hide: "slide",
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var url = $('.header a').attr('href');
            //alert(url);
            $(".dialog").load(url); //use the previously saved id
        }
    });

    $('.header a').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.dialog').dialog('open');
        //$('#dialog').load(url);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnm2n/12/)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what should i use here?
I also tried same code with/without destroy method and it didn't work either

Comment: remove or comment `$(this).dialog('destroy');`

Comment: No sir still not success, i know about browser cache

Comment: I see that working perfectly on jsfiddle but not on my side. Maybe the library you used on jsfiddle is of 1.8.16 and i am using 1.8.0. tested it on jsfiddle like that and same results i am still testing.

Comment: Can you give me 1.8.0 ? I can't find it. Post it on jsfiddle or some other way

Comment: My bad bro, it was 1.6.3 and 1.7.2. I have tested locally on both but failed ;(

Comment: I am putting up code on fiddle you to view it in 1.8.0 and fix it that way.

Comment: this fiddle is with the jquery 1.8.0, not with the jquery-ui 1.8.0 . there is no dialog at all. Post the errors from your console

Comment: I have updated my exact html code with what you did on Fiddle but still it ain't working for me :(

Comment: For now I can suggest you to make a `test case` with your `html` from browser, css, all js (all with correct paths) and load it on some filesharing service (http://files.privacysucks.com/ for instance), or provide a link to your page

Comment: Here bro. check this file, it is not working i don't know why whereas on jsfiddle code works fine with these libraries.
[TESTFILE](http://files.privacysucks.com/5621b6457c60f56f121ff3a753e597f5/testfile.php)

Comment: @Jahanzab Anwar could you please provide a testcase with your exact problem. Your file is full of errors (invalid characters, incorrect paths to scripts etc.). Can you make a test with only dialogbox which is opened only once, but not twice. Please not php, but html, so I  do not need to create a virtualhost for it